# how to initialize a standard field value whose type is of hierarchy in apex?

Tags: apex, hierarchy

how to initialize a standard field value whose type is of hierarchy in apex?

Account a.ParentId=??

where parentId is a required field and it is of type hierarchy. How should I set its value in my apex code?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such type as "hierarchy", really. It's just a lookup field. You populate it with the `Id` of another Account. (And the system won't let you create a reference cycle in your hierarchy).

`ParentId` is *not* a required field.